# Read app.config of SharePoint project into console application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am having one SharePoint project with app.config file.

Creating another console application with some business logic where I want to access those application settings.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: So both apps are console/winforms or is one of them a web app?

Comment: One is web app- sharepoint project and another one is console. from console wants to read app.config of web app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Application Settings Manager from Microsoft's patterns and practices group to store your settings, instead of web.config.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798488.aspx